# Recharts line chart cut off top line

Tags: reactjs, linechart, recharts

I am using recharts line chart it's working nicely but sometimes cut off top of the line. 
Please check the snippet in jsfiddle.

```
const {LineChart, Line, XAxis, YAxis, ReferenceLine, CartesianGrid, Tooltip, Legend} = Recharts;
const data = [
 {"Date":"16 May","Download":"40717"},{"Date":"17 May","Download":"39640"},{"Date":"18 May","Download":"52122"},{"Date":"19 May","Download":"51800"},{"Date":"20 May","Download":"49605"},{"Date":"21 May","Download":"45601"},{"Date":"22 May","Download":"43798"},{"Date":"23 May","Download":"36113"},{"Date":"24 May","Download":"278531"},{"Date":"25 May","Download":"323521"},{"Date":"26 May","Download":"154527"},{"Date":"27 May","Download":"119990"},{"Date":"28 May","Download":"100524"},{"Date":"29 May","Download":"83121"},{"Date":"30 May","Download":"60536"},{"Date":"31 May","Download":"58208"},{"Date":"01 Jun","Download":"304154"},{"Date":"02 Jun","Download":"538870"},{"Date":"03 Jun","Download":"213244"},{"Date":"04 Jun","Download":"130246"},{"Date":"05 Jun","Download":"104131"},{"Date":"06 Jun","Download":"72564"},{"Date":"07 Jun","Download":"69012"},{"Date":"08 Jun","Download":"96166"},{"Date":"09 Jun","Download":"89748"},{"Date":"10 Jun","Download":"80895"},{"Date":"11 Jun","Download":"155434"},{"Date":"12 Jun","Download":"81735"},{"Date":"13 Jun","Download":"56838"}
];
const SimpleLineChart = React.createClass({
    render () {
    return (
        <LineChart width={600} height={300} data={data}
            margin={{top: 0, right: 50, left: 20, bottom: 5}}>
       <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3"/>
       <XAxis dataKey="Date"/>
       <YAxis/>
       <Tooltip/>
       <Legend />

       <Line type="monotone" dataKey="Download" stroke="#8884d8" />

      </LineChart>
    );
  }
})

ReactDOM.render(
  <SimpleLineChart />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rafiul_fiddle/tp0zL5s1/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Issue :**

The issue is due to `"Download":"40717"`

---

**Solution :**

convert `download` -> `string` to `int`

```
// data={data.map(d => ({...d , "Download" : +d.Download }))

<LineChart 
  width={600} 
  height={300} 
  data={data.map(d => ({...d , "Download" : +d.Download }))} // <---- HERE
  margin={{top: 0, right: 50, left: 20, bottom: 5}}>
```

**[WORKING DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/whf1vm0p/4/)**

Comment: Awesome! It's working perfectly. Thanks @Vivek Doshi. You are a genius :)